# Is there a way to specify the y-axis crossing point?

Tags: echarts

In the example below the y-axis crosses at 1, rather than 0. Is there a way to achieve this in echarts?

[image: excel example]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, literally, you can't do this with basic bar chart because it will break the coordinate system and result will be anything but not a bar chart.

1. If you need **only visual** like on attached picture then you can [hide xAxis](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.show) and draw its surrogate with [markLine](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.markLine) but you will have the troubles with bar positioning (that will fix with stack and transparent bars, see below).
2. If you need **real chart** with responsive, zoomable and other opts then in the Echarts you can use [custom series](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Custom%20Series) for build own chart type (see [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=custom-profit)).

Example how to make picture like attached:

[image]

```js
  var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
  var option = {
    tooltip: {},
    xAxis: {
      data: ['Category-1', 'Category-2', 'Category-3', 'Category-4'],
      show: true,
      axisLine: {
        show: true,
        lineStyle: {
          opacity: 0
        }
      },
      axisTick: {
        show: false,
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
        max: 4,
      min: -1
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Series-1',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'group',
      data: [1, 1, -3],
      color: 'rgba(0,0,0, 0)',
    }, {
      name: 'Series-2',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'group',
      data: [{
        value: 1,
        itemStyle: {
          color: 'red'
        }
      }, {
        value: 2,
        itemStyle: {
          color: 'green'
        }
      }, {
        value: 1,
        itemStyle: {
          color: 'orange'
        }
      }],
      markLine: {
        symbol: "none",
        data: [{
          silent: false,
          yAxis: 1,
          lineStyle: {
            color: "#000",
            width: 1,
            type: "solid"
          }
        }, ],
        label: {
          show: false,
        }
      },
    }]
  };

  myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.8.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

P.S. If this not a secret, why you need it?

Comment: For example if you want to present a chart saying: "Region A has 2 times more cases than region B". You could work with percentages, but sometimes it is easier for people to grasp "2 times more or 4 times more".

Comment: My question about xAxis that moved from 0 to 1. I have hypothesis that it's something from real world where zero value is missing or doesn't make sense, right? This is one of most hardest changes in any charts because break Cartesian coordinate system.